# what do the Targeting methods, Recorders, wizards and The object repository do?

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I’m taking the “UI Automation with Studio” course, part of the RPA Developer Foundation on UiPath.
I’m really confused by it. Can anyone please recommend other video or article/tutorial that explains UI Automation with Studio.

I didn’t understand why there are two different types of experience(Modern experience and classic experience). Also, I didn’t understand what the Targeting methods, Recorders, wizards and The object repository do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're doing it through the UiPath Academy then I'd highly recommend trying the examples in each courses.

On the Design Experiences, essentially earlier in the year they released the 'Modern Design Experience' which has options like an Object Repository. Some Activities have been changed from the Classic Experience has been replaced with alternatives like instead of "On Element Exists (Classic)" is now "Check App State (Modern)"

The Object Repository is essentially a Library of UI Elements (buttons, labels, dropdowns) that you've previously used. It means you can copy the Repository to different Projects, so for example if you use the same Website in two different projects, then you can save time by re-using those elements.